# Same Query, Same Database, Different Results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

My mind is completely blown by this. The exact same query is returning zero results when run with mysqli_query(), but with the expected two results via phpmyadmin. I have double and triple checked I am running the same query.

The PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT assignment_id, next_deadline FROM " . TBL_ASSIGNMENTS . " WHERE ( next_deadline >= $after_from AND next_deadline < $after_to ) OR ( next_deadline >= $before_from AND next_deadline < $before_to ) AND stage = 1";
$result = $db->query($sql);
if ( !$result )
{
    trigger_error($db->error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}

die('Count: '.$db->numRows($result).'<br /><br />'.$sql);
```

The $db object is a simple wrapper for the mysqli functions I have been using for a long time, so the problem is not there. The wrapper is working for similar queries elsewhere.

The output:

```
Count: 0

SELECT assignment_id, next_deadline FROM assignments WHERE ( next_deadline >= 1400306400 AND next_deadline < 1400310000 ) OR ( next_deadline >= 1400436000 AND next_deadline < 1400439600 ) AND stage = 1
```

I am then running this same SQL query (Ced + Ped) in phpmyadmin, and getting the expected 2 results.

Note I have also looped the results and counted manually without using mysqli_num_rows, with the same outcome.

Any ideas what could be causing this? My mind really is blown, after all, phpmyadmin is also running them via PHP...

PS, incase you doubt the wrapper, here are the relevant functions:

```
function __construct(){ 
$this->link = mysqli_connect($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($this->link, 'utf8');
$this->config = $this->createConfig();
// tell the server to run the close function on script shutdown
register_shutdown_function(array(&$this, 'close'));
}
function query($query){
$this->lastQuery = $query;
$this->querycount++;
$timestart = microtime(true);
$result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query);
$querytime = microtime(true) - $timestart;
$this->querytotal = $this->querytotal + $querytime;
$this->queryarray[$this->querycount] = array('query' => $query, 'time' => $querytime);
return $result;
}
function numRows($result){
return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help you may be able to give..

Chris

Edit: 
Now also tried variants of the same sql query to no avail, including added parenthesis:

```
SELECT assignment_id, next_deadline FROM assignments WHERE ( ( next_deadline >= 1400306400 AND next_deadline < 1400310000 ) OR ( next_deadline >= 1400436000 AND next_deadline < 1400439600 ) ) AND stage = 1
```

I have also tried removing the stage = 1 off the end, to isolate the issue, and running each of the parenthesis on their own, but no luck. e.g.

```
SELECT assignment_id, next_deadline FROM assignments WHERE next_deadline >= 1400306400 AND next_deadline < 1400310000
```

Comment: Are you running the same version and variant of SQL on both?

Comment: Both the web app and phpmyadmin are on the same server as the database (MySQL 5.5.37), connecting to localhost. Both using php-fpm. To make it even more mind boggling, both are also using mysqli

Comment: I'm giving a shot, but maybe the `WHERE` filter with timestamp works different in PHPMyadmin and mysqli. I mean, PHPMyAdmin can be manipulating somehow and showing right results and mysqli does not have that function.

Comment: phpmyadmin is using mysqli too, according to the phpmyadmin front page. I did also think phpmyadmin might be 'correcting' the sql query in some way, but using variants which certainly cannot be wrong syntax produces the same result (see the edit at the bottom of my question).

Comment: I understand they're the same database, but I was asking if they're using the same version of SQL (a.k.a. the system used to parse the statement and actually retrieve the values). It's possible one of the two was using an older version of mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP doc (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php):

If you have problems making work this num_rows, you have to declare ->store_result() first.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root", "", "tables");

$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1");
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
```

In your case, consider procedural style defined at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php

Comment: Unfortunately, as mentioned in my question, I have looped and counted the returned result manually to check it was not a problem with num_rows.

Comment: Have you checked for database user's permission to select?

Comment: Yes. Same user used in both the PHP and phpmyadmin. The same user is also being used successfully elsewhere on the website, indeed, in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to 'fix' this, but with no diagnosis of the issue!

Restarting the mysql server (service mysql restart) did not work, but rebooting the server (reboot) did.

I regret this does not help as to what caused the issue. If anyone has any ideas, feel free to enlighten!

Thanks for your answers,

Chris

Comment: It probably finally installed all those software updates that needed a restart. :P

Comment: I wish the solution was that simple! The server was a fresh install only a few days ago, as I switched from Apache 2.2 to 2.4, mod_php to php-fpm and Ubuntu 12.10 to 14.04. With all those changes, I thought fresh was probably wiser :)

Answer (score 0):

The PM;U reason for this is that you're pointing to different databases.

SQL is supposed to have the same behaviour always.

Make sure that if you're reading from slave and writing in master the sync process is working correctly.

Also check config files, etc.

To see where the queries are executed monitor the activity with mysqladmin in your database server.

Hope this help.

Cheers,
Jesus